# Using g++ how can I link with a library that was built using gcc?

Tags: gcc, g++, linker, name-mangling

I am trying to link a .a library that was built with gcc to a program built using g++.  But the name mangling is different.  How can I do this?
Thanks,
CP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your C++ code, you just need to wrap your includes of the gcc library header file(s) in extern "C":

```
extern "C" {
#include "my_library.h"
}
```